# If every point is an umbilical point then the principal curvatures are constant

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, curvature

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be an embedded surface, then $II(X, Y)=\langle X, AY \rangle$, where $II$ is the second fundamental form, and $A:T_xM \to T_xM$ is an endomorphism. If all points of $M$ are umbilical cords, ie the eigenvalues of $A$ coincide for every $x \in M$, then the principal curvatures, that is the eigenvalues of $A$, are constant.

Here's what I got:

Let $v \in T_xM$ be an eigenvector of $A$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then there's a geodesic $\gamma: (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to M$ with $\gamma(0)=x, \ \gamma'(0)=v.$ Let $X$ be a section extending the geodesic, then: $$II(X,X):=\langle \nabla_X X, \ n \rangle=\langle \nabla_{\gamma'} \gamma', \ n \rangle=\langle 0, \ n \rangle=0$$

But we also have $$II(X,X)=\langle X, \ AX \rangle=\lambda \langle v, v \rangle= \lambda ||v||^2 $$

Hence $\lambda ||v||^2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda = 0.$ Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ are constant.

I'm not convinced my proof is correct so some feedback would be great.

Comment: So the sphere has curvature $0$? Your mistake is to say that lines of curvature are geodesics.

Comment: On more serious inspection, what do you mean by $\nabla$ here?

Comment: @TedShifrin $\nabla$ corresponds to the levi civita connection.

Comment: @TedShifrin But I can find geodesics in the direction of lines of curvature.

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection on which manifold?

Comment: @TedShifrin The Levi Civita connection on $M$.

Comment: That’s one of the problems… With that, the second fundamental form would always be zero.

Comment: @TedShifrin why is that?

Comment: Because you’re dotting a tangent vector with the normal. Review all the concepts.